# Prevent ROS2 Timer Callback Queuing

Tags: timer, ros2

ROS2 timer adds elements to the callback queue. In a single threaded (C++) node, when a timer callback execution time exceeds the timer period, the spinner would be flooded with timer callbacks. This will cause a degradation in node responsivity to other (subscriber) callbacks.

Is there a way to make a ROS node to hold only one timer's callback instance in a queue at a time?